# run jQuery statement inside typeahead.js' "on selected" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

Sorry for the title - that was my fourth attempt....

I'm running a `typeahead.js` that's working perfectly, but I want to run an additional command upon the user selecting an item from the dropdown it creates and it's not working.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(
{   hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3
},
{
    displayKey: 'name',    
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div><strong>{{name}}</strong> <div class='suggestion'>{{m}} > {{n}}</div></div>")
    },    
    source: list.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 9}).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {    
      a  = datum.name;
      b  = datum.m;
      c  = datum.n;

    /* when the user selects an item, this function runs, setting */
    /* variables a, b, and c.  I also want to .addClass and removeClass, */
    /*  but the code doesn't run. */
      $('#search').addClass('fa-unhappy');
      $('#search').removeClass('fa-happy');    
});
```

I can run it elsewhere in a separate function - the id `search` does exist at the time the function is running, I'm just not sure why it doesn't add and remove the classes I'm asking it to.

Here's the HTML for that if for some reason it makes a difference:

```
<i id="search" class="fa fa-2x fa-check-square uCheck fa-unhappy"></i>
```

and the CSS...

```
.fa-happy {
  color: green;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: color 1.5s ease;
}
```

What's interesting is if I put something like this:

```
console.log($('#search').width());
```

into the function it returns the correct value, so I know it can find the element with the id `search`.

## update

Ok.... to make matters even weirder, I can do it in vanilla js, but not jquery:

```
var d = document.getElementById("search");      
d.className = "fa fa-2x fa-check-square uCheck fa-happy";
```

Which makes no sense to me because the jQuery library is needed for `typeahead.js` to work, (and I'm sure it's loaded in the page...)

Comment: So on your `typeahead:selected` event, do you want to set `#search` to have the `fa-happy` class? Because that is not what you're doing. You're adding `fa-unhappy` and removing `fa-happy`.  Maybe you just have the addClass/removeClass functions switched?

Comment: ................ I am so freaking retarded.  Sometimes it's the simple things in life that get you....... :)

Comment: No problem, we've all had those moments! :). I often find when I'm just totally scratching my head, its helpful to step through the lines of code with the JS debugger. Are you familiar with using Chrome's built-in debugger? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/?hl=en . If not, I'd recommend reading that article and practicing some of the methods they include. It is very useful and can help in those "pulling-my-hair-out" situations.

Comment: yeah I use it all the time, I just kept going over it in my head and didn't see my `.addClass` and `.removeClass` were switched :)  Phew.  that was driving me nuts!